# my operator is still running after dag fails to run in airflow

Tags: airflow

[image: Dag Figure]

As seen above picture, TAB_click_count Operator and COVERAGE_poi Operator do not run. still running.

Just one time my DAG was failed to run because of those two operators. 
And i fixed that. But after error occur, two operators are not finished still running when my dag runs.

I tried to trigger the dag, but same.

What is problem to my dag or operator?

Comment: Please also add your dag definition

Comment: could it have to do something with [`depends_on_past`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2357)?

Comment: @y2k-shubham right. it is because of setting depends_on_past=True. I misunderstand this option.. I changed this option to False.

Comment: **@andres.chkim** I'd suggest you add an answer of your own detailing the problem and solution for reference of others